# Значение и количество повторяющихся элементов массива

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток.

Есть одномерный массив из 10 элементов (положительных и отрицательных), которые генерируются рандомно.

Требуется найти произведение одинаковых отрицательных элементов, т.е. проверить элементы на отрицательность, получить значения элементов, которые повторяются 2 и больше раз, возвести это число в кол-во повторений этого числа, вывести.

Например, массив:
-1 2 -3 -5 -3 4 -3 -5 2 6

Выходит: -3 повторяется 3 раза, -5 повторяется 2 раза.
Нужно посчитать -3^3 и -5^2 и вывести: какое число повторяется, сколько раз и результат (-27 и 25 соответственно).

Начальная генерация массива:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    system("cls");;
    int ARR[10], i, j, num=0, P=1;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Array:\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        ARR[i]=rand() % 11 - 7;
        printf("%i\t", ARR[i]);
    }

    /*

    */
}
```

Изучил несколько подобных тем, но ни один код не заработал верно. В какую сторону копать?

Спасибо.

Comment: ну самый просто вариант - в сторону циклов =) Более умный - в сторону сортировки и/или деревьев.

Comment: как раз рассматривал вариант с форами, вплоть до вложенных, но не заработало

Comment: `qsort` - отсортировали. Идем от минимальных. Если рядом есть одинаковые отрицательные - считаем, выводим  (только учтите, что (-5)^2 - это 25, а не -25 :)). Кончились отрицательные числа - остановились...

Comment: запрещено использовать дополнительные функции, лишь циклы, но все равно сначала отсортировать массив, а потом считать элементы?

Comment: Самое главное, если несколько пар парных элементов, то как запомнить и число и кол-во повторений в каждой паре.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать только циклы, не меняя сам исходный массив, то один из подходов может выглядеть следующим образом, как показано в демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N] = { -1, 2, -3, -5, -3, 4, -3, -5, 2, 6 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < 0 )
        {
            size_t j = 0;
            while ( j < i && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;
            if ( j == i )
            {
                size_t n = 0;
                for ( size_t k = i + 1; k < N; k++ )
                {
                    if ( a[k] == a[i] ) ++n;
                }

                if ( n != 0 )
                {
                    long long int product = a[i];
                    for ( size_t k = 0; k < n; k++ ) product *= a[i];

                    printf( "%d is repeated %zu times and the result is equal to %lld\n", 
                        a[i], n + 1, product );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
-3 is repeated 3 times and the result is equal to -27
-5 is repeated 2 times and the result is equal to 25
```

Answer (score 0):

В PHP такая задача решается совсем просто.

```
// Production of matched negative values
$arr = [ -1, 2, -3, -5, -3, 4, -3, -5, 2, 6 ];
var_dump($arr);
$arr_cnt = array_count_values($arr);
var_dump($arr_cnt);
foreach ($arr_cnt as $key => $value) {
    if(($key < 0) && ($value > 1)) {
        $power = abs($key) ** $value;
        if($value & 1) $power = - $power;
        echo "<br>($key)<sup>$value</sup> = $power";
    }
}
```

Результаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разберём основные моменты этого решения

1. Функция `array_count_values()` подсчитывает количество повторов числа в массиве. Для массива из 10 чисел это можно сделать "в лоб", "прогуливаясь" с каждым встреченным отрицательным числом по массиву. Чтобы избежать повторов, достаточно менять найденные числа на единицы.
2. В приведённом примере в степень возводился модуль элемента, а знак вычислялся проверкой на чётность. Но если уж всё равно идти по массиву, то можно считать степень через умножение и не думать о знаке.

Итак:

```
// Production of matched negative values
$arr = [ -1, 2, -3, -5, -3, 4, -3, -5, 2, 6 ];
var_dump($arr);

$b = $arr;
$n = count($b);
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    if($b[$i] < 0){
        $k = $b[$i];
        $pow = $k;
        $deg = 1;
        for($j= $i+1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            if ($b[$j] == $k) {
                $deg++;
                $b[$j] = 1;
                $pow *= $k;
            }
        }
        if($deg>1) echo "<br>($k)<sup>$deg</sup> = $pow";
    }
}
```

с тем же результатом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, что перевод второго варианта на C затруднений не вызовет.